# Set environment variable from outside bash

Tags: php, bash, environment-variables

I'm trying to set a bash environment variable using PHP (from command line) with no success.

```
$buff=array();
$buff[]="VARTESTKEY=VARTESTVALUE";
$buff[]="export VARTESTKEY";
file_put_contents('script.sh', implode("\n",$buff));
system('source script.sh');
```

I've even tried using a script to output the key value which gets evaled:

```
$buff=array();
$buff[]="echo VARTESTKEY=VARTESTVALUE";
file_put_contents('script.sh', implode("\n",$buff));
system('eval "$(bash script.sh)"');
```

But still nothing.

Any ideas? I don't mind using any other tool (perl, python, c, etc.) as long as it can do its job by being called from the PHP system function.

Comment: Do you get any access permission errors? Check your error.log.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention it but this is from the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need this environment variables before running another bash script?

You can just use `putenv("KEY=VAL");`

Es:

```
<?php
putenv("ASD=LOL");
system("echo \$ASD");
?>
```

Edit:

```
<?php 
echo "VARTESTKEY=VARTESTVALUE";
?>
```

launch it as:

```
$ eval `php script.php` && echo $VARTESTKEY
```

Comment: That looks like it would work if I was running some other script from the same PHP script. But I'm not. I need the variable to exist after the PHP script ends.

Comment: So you will use this script in a way like this: `$ php script.php && ./other_command.sh`. Am I right?

Comment: Even more low tech: php script.php && echo $VARTESTKEY

Comment: I worked out a variation of your answer but thats the general idea!