# How to pass PHP variables to Shell Script?

Tags: php, bash, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pass parameters to php with shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803025/pass-parameters-to-php-with-shell)

I am running a php script within shell script as

```
#! /bin/sh

php file.php
```

Shell will run the script and display the output of the php script, but how can I pass variable defined within php script into shell script to be used therein (for further processing by shell)?

For example, consider a php file of

```
<?php
$test = "something";
?>
```

How can I pass the value of `$test` to the shell script as

```
#! /bin/sh

php config.php
echo $test
```

**UPDATE:** The methods suggested are based on `print`ing the variables. I prefer not to print out anything, as the php script has other applications too (to be `include`d in other php scripts).

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747396/set-environment-variable-from-outside-bash

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP script can print shell-style variable assignments:

```
print("VAR1=foo\n");
print("VAR2=bar\n");
```

In your shell script, you will need to evaluate these assignments, in order to import them into your environment:

```
. <(php file.php)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP script can print the values and your shell script can use process or command substitution or `read` to retrieve the values.

PHP:

```
<?php
    print($test1 . "\n");
    print($test2 . "\n");
?>
```

Bash:

```
while read -r line
do
    something_with "$line"
done < <(php_script)
```

or

```
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
array=($(php_script))
IFS=$saveIFS
```

or

```
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
read -r -d '' var1 var2 <<< "$(php_script)"
IFS=$saveIFS
```

or other variations.